# get specific range of enum values in csharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get a range of enum values in razor page.
This is the enum:

```
 public enum MessageCategory
{       
    UserConfirmationCode=1000,       
    UserConfirmOrder=1001,      
    UserDiscount=1002,      
    AdminProductQuantity=2000,      
    AdminConfirmOrder=2001
}
```

I want to get those items of enum where has value between 1000 and 2000in foreach loop.
This is what I did:

```
 @foreach (Enum contact in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ContactType)))
        { 
          //html codes
        }
```

I want the iterating enum in foreach have condition to get values >1000 & <2000.
Is it possible?
Thank you in advance

Comment: This seems awfully hacky to me. If you only need certain values, perhaps you should have a different enum for every group of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you question you show `MessageCategory` but in the foreach you talk about `ContactType` i am assuming this is a typo.
But i would do something like this:

```
foreach (var contact in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MessageCategory)).OfType<MessageCategory>().Where(m =>(int)m < 2000 && (int)m >1000))
{
      Console.WriteLine(contact);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at this, might help:

```cs
public enum MessageCategory
{       
    UserConfirmationCode = 1000,       
    UserConfirmOrder = 1001,      
    UserDiscount = 1002,      
    AdminProductQuantity = 2000,      
    AdminConfirmOrder = 2001
}
foreach (var item in Enum
     .GetValues(typeof(MessageCategory))
     .Cast<MessageCategory>()
     // Any Specific Range
     .Where(x => (int) x > 1001))
{ 
   //html codes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the most simple form I could think of, no unnecassary casting:

```
foreach (var msg in Enum.GetValues<MessageCategory>()
                .Where(x=>(int)x>=1000 && (int)x<=2000))
{
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

if you want it inside the for-each, you can cast it

```
foreach (var msg in Enum.GetValues<MessageCategory>())
{
   if ((int) msg >= 1000 && (int) msg <= 2000)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(msg);
   }
}
```

will print

```
UserConfirmationCode
UserConfirmOrder
UserDiscount
AdminProductQuantity
```

a bit more clean way and testable way is to create a method for your code range check:

```
 // name it however you want or think is resonable
 private bool IsUserTypeCode(MessageCategory msg) 
 {
     return (int) msg >= 1000 && (int) msg <= 2000;
 }
```

now you can give it as a predicate to the Where clause like this:

```
foreach (var suit in Enum.GetValues<MessageCategory>()
                .Where(IsUserTypeCode))
{
    Console.WriteLine(suit);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in c# the enum is cast to the underlying value (int I assume in your case), so evaluating an enum to check if it's in the range it's as simple as

```
if(contact >= 2000 && contact <= 2000)
```

but, if you need a list of the possible enums in that range, say for instance you want to put them in a combobox, then what we do is to list all enums with a method like this

```
public static List<TEnum> GetAllValues<TEnum>() where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    if(typeof(TEnum).IsEnum == false) { throw new ArgumentException("EnumUtility.GetAllValues<TEnum> : TEnum must be an enum"); }
    Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum));
    List<TEnum> toRet = new List<TEnum>();
    for(int i = 0; i< values.Length; i++)
    {
        toRet.Add((TEnum)values.GetValue(i));
    }
    return toRet;
}
```

then you can do something like:

```
List<MessageCategory> desiredEnums = EnumUtilities.GetAllValues<MessageCategory>()
    .Where(x => x >= 2000 && x <= 3000)
    .ToList();
```

Hopefully this will be helpful

Comment: The reason i downvoted this is because you can validate against the underlying type by casting, and your answer is way to complicated .